# IDXGIObject::GetParent and Release

Tags: com, dxgi

The `IDXGIObject` has a function to obtain a pointer to its parent [`GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee421924%28VS.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately, the docs don't say whether I have to call `Release()` on the returned interface or not -- calling or not calling it works fine in both debug/release (that is, no crash), but I wonder whether I should release or rather not. Any idea how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, GetParent() adds a reference to the returned objects, so you need to call Release () on them.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee421925%28VS.85%29.aspx) "If the data returned is a pointer to an IUnknown, or one of its derivative classes, previously set by IDXGIObject::SetPrivateDataInterface, then ::Release() must be called on the pointer before the pointer is freed to decrement the reference count."

I would recommend calling release.

Comment: That's GetPrivateData, not GetParent -- I wonder whether the same holds true for GetParent.

Comment: COM's convention is that callers always release returned data. I've written about this here: http://www.winwonk.com/writing/commemory/. Now, DirectX probably won't allow cross-process calls, so I'm not sure if they play tricks with ownership for performance reasons. However, not calling `Release` in this case should yield a memory leak.